# Lazy IO + Parallelism: converting an image to grayscale

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I am trying to add parallelism to a program that converts a .bmp to a grayscale .bmp.  I am seeing usually 2-4x worse performance for the parallel code.  I am tweaking parBuffer / chunking sizes and still cannot seem to reason about it.  Looking for guidance.

The entire source file used here: http://lpaste.net/106832

We use `Codec.BMP` to read in a stream of pixels represented by `type RGBA = (Word8, Word8, Word8, Word8)`.  To convert to grayscale, simply map a 'luma' transform across all the pixels.

The serial implementation is literally:

```
toGray :: [RGBA] -> [RGBA]
toGray x = map luma x
```

The test input .bmp is 5184 x 3456 (71.7 MB).

The serial implementation runs in ~10s, ~550ns/pixel.  Threadscope looks clean:

[image: serial]

Why is this so fast?  I suppose it has something with lazy ByteString (even though Codec.BMP uses strict ByteString--is there implicit conversion occurring here?) and fusion.

**Adding Parallelism**

First attempt at adding parallelism was via `parList`.  Oh boy.  The program used ~4-5GB memory and system started swapping.

I then read "Parallelizing Lazy Streams with parBuffer" section of Simon Marlow's O'Reilly book and tried `parBuffer` with a large size.  This still did not produce desirable performance.  The spark sizes were incredibly small.

I then tried to increase the spark size by chunking the lazy list and then sticking with `parBuffer` for the parallelism:

```
toGrayPar :: [RGBA] -> [RGBA]
toGrayPar x = concat $ (withStrategy (parBuffer 500 rpar) . map (map luma))
                       (chunk 8000 x)

chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk n [] = []
chunk n xs = as : chunk n bs where
  (as,bs) = splitAt (fromIntegral n) xs
```

But this still does not yield desirable performance:

```
  18,934,235,760 bytes allocated in the heap
  15,274,565,976 bytes copied during GC
     639,588,840 bytes maximum residency (27 sample(s))
     238,163,792 bytes maximum slop
            1910 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     35277 colls, 35277 par   19.62s   14.75s     0.0004s    0.0234s
  Gen  1        27 colls,    26 par   13.47s    7.40s     0.2741s    0.5764s

  Parallel GC work balance: 30.76% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 6 (1 bound, 5 peak workers (5 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 4480 (2240 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 2 GC'd, 2238 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  MUT     time   14.31s  ( 14.75s elapsed)
  GC      time   33.09s  ( 22.15s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.01s  (  0.12s elapsed)
  Total   time   47.41s  ( 37.02s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,323,504,434 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  30.2% of total user, 38.7% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 7433188
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 1017408
```

[image: par1]

How can I better reason about what is going on here?

Comment: Have you established a reasonable baseline time? How long does it take to just calculate the length of the `[RGBA]`? Since your other comments indicate that this value is being streamed with lazy IO, it's quite possible the IO time will always dominate whatever processing your doing, parallel or not.  So how much of the run time is just IO and parsing?

Comment: I can try to see how long the IO and Codec.BMP parsing takes.  The baseline I am using is the serial implementation which takes ~10 s.  I think this is useful enough to compare against 30-40s that parallel implementation takes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a big list of RGBA pixels. Why don't you use `parListChunk` with a reasonable chunk size?

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment than an answer, it doesn't solve OP's problem but just makes a suggestion for something to try.

Comment: parListChunk forces the spine of the [5184 x 3456] image which takes many GB of memory.  I am trying to avoid that and still use lazy IO.